# How to use aggregate function without GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM student;
NAME                 ID                AGE      MARK1      MARK2      TOTAL   
-------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -----------
Ananda               200                22         90         95
Chris                250                18         80         75
Gokul                325                17         50         50

SQL> SELECT MAX(mark1),name FROM student;
SELECT MAX(mark1),name FROM student
                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
```

As you can see the error,
can anyone suggest me a query to select the Maximum mark from the table
and display it along with the corresponding name of the student??

Is it even possible without using GROUP BY clause?
As you can see, there's no logical way of using GROUP BY clause here.

Comment: It does not make sense to include an aggregate *and* a non-aggregate that is *not* part of the grouping. An aggregate alone would have been fine; adding in the non-aggregate name column just doesn't make sense - which name should be chosen?

Comment: error message clearly says its oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an easy solution:

```
SELECT mark1,name
FROM student
WHERE mark1=
(SELECT MAX(mark1) FROM student);
```

Result:

```
MARK1 NAME
----- -------
   90 Ananda
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get the name of the student also, you need to use a join:

```
SELECT T2.Mark,T1.name 
FROM student T1 JOIN
    (SELECT MAX(Mark1) as Mark 
     FROM student) T2 on T1.Mark=T2.mark
```

Result:

```
MAXMARK  NAME
------------
90       Ananda
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/60977f/4)

Comment: @GokulNC: feel free to accept the answer if you solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

If am not wrong you just need `Order by` and `ROWNUM`

```
select * from 
(
SELECT mark1,name FROM student Order by Mark1 desc
)
Where  ROWNUM = 1
```

or You can use `Analytic functions`

```
select * from 
(
SELECT Row_number()over(order by Mark1 desc) as RN,mark1,name FROM student 
)
Where  RN = 1.
```

If there is a tie in max mark and you want all the rows with max marks then use `Dense_Rank` instead of `Row_number`

Comment: Downvoters usually do not care to explain. They just leave a downvote and gone. Im not the downvoter, FYI.

Comment: @RagingBull - yep got used to it :)

Comment: Thank you :)
That did it.
But as a beginner to SQL, I find it a little difficult :)

Comment: Approch 1: Given below error:The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries,